Proxmox giving error Remounting filesystem read-only even after clone on brand new nvme
My server spec:
MB: Supermicro H12SSL-i
CPU: AMD Epyc 7742
GPU: NVIDIA RTX 3090
RAM: 512GB DDR4 RDIMM ECC

Today my Proxmox 8 nded up having the following error:
[40.294701] EXT-fs error (device dm-1): ext_journal_check_start:84: comm systemd-journal: Detected aborted journal
EXT4-fs (dm-1): Remounting filesystem read-only

This error appears like ~30 seconds after I load proxmox and even I can write my username and password and In a few seconds BOOM I get the error shown above.
First thing that I thought it might be the 2TB samsung NVME is dying on me. I run only one drive in the server. Luckaly I have two brand new nvme from Samsung again and they are even 4TBs. So I downloaded Clonezilla and initiated a clone from the old "suposadly" broken nvme of 2TB to the brand new 4TB nvme. The clone went sucessfully!
So I installed the new 4TB nvme and BOOM, the same error even on the brand new hard drive.
To make the things even more wierder I took that 4TB hard drive and place it on another machine where I had Ubuntu 22.04 installed. I remove the Ubuntu nvme and installed the 4TB cloned Proxmox on the machine and there Proxmox loads and runs fine on my PC and there Proxmox starts without showing me this error, but on the SuperMicro server it does not.
There on the PC which used to run my Ubuntu when I installed the 2TB initial drive from the server for even greater suprise it was runing without any kind of errors the same way the 4TB cloned was running.
So I decided to run test command to see if the disk is healthy and I executed sudo smartctl -a /dev/nvme0n1 on which I've got:
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

If that result is acurate the disk should be fine, and why not it runs on my regular PC just fine. Why it does not on my SuperMicro Server ?
To test the server I took the nvme of my Ubuntu PC and place it on the server just to conclude even weirder result, the ubuntu loads in the same nvme slot in which it refuses to load the inital 2TB or the cloned 4TB nvme drives containing Proxmox.
How these strange outcomes can happen, anyone have a clue ?
This setup was running like this for months wihtout problems. What should I do not to make my Proxmox back online without this nasty comm systemd-journal: Detected aborted journal, any advice ?

hey, have you recently did any PCIe pass through? I have recently done that (inbuilt SATA, not HBA) and got this corruption. Trying to edit grub as suggested here -https://forum.proxmox.com/threads/filesystem-corruption-after-pcie-passthrough.100089/

I am using a Samsung SSD 990 PRO, and the problem was fixed by setting "nvme_core.default_ps_max_latency_us=0".
https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Solid_state_drive/NVMe#Controller_failure_due_to_broken_APST_support
https://qiita-com.translate.goog/Shunmo17/items/8d4a9e541a4bc837c99c?_x_tr_sl=ja&_x_tr_tl=en&_x_tr_hl=ja&_x_tr_pto=wapp
